# A Seemingly Geographic Riddle

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography, music, history

1. Selçuk, İzmir Province, Turkey.
2. Bodrum, Muğla Province, Turkey.
3. Yassıhüyük, Ankara Province, Turkey.
4. Sart, Manisa Province, Turkey.
5. ???
6. İzmir, İzmir Province, Turkey.
7. Atalanti, Phthiotis, Greece.

**Explain why the blank cannot be filled.**

Comment: If this helps anyone… (spoiler!!) https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ9nx.png

Comment: @msh210 No, I'm not measuring distance of anything geographical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [geography](/questions/tagged/geography) tag:

> Well, all cities are in the Asian part of Western Turkey with the exception of Atalanti in Greece. But you knew that – it's explicitly stated in the question. And because the puzzle is only "seemingly" geographic, as the title claims, the location of the cities probably isn't the important thing here.

The [history](/questions/tagged/history) tag:

> In Ancient times, these towns were Greek settlements:
>
>   Selçuk was **[Ephesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephesus)**, the largest city in **Ionia**.
>   Bodrum was **[Halicarnassus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halicarnassus)**, a **Dorian** settlement.
>   Yassıhüyük was **[Gordion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordion)**, capital of **Phrygia**.
>   Sart was **[Sardis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardis)**, capital of **Lydia**.
>   İzmir was **[Smyrna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smyrna)**, an **Aeolian** settlement.
>   **[Atalanti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atalanti)** already had its present name. It was capital of the **Locris** province.

The [music](/questions/tagged/music) tag:

> The regions of these cities have given the name to the **[diatonic scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatonic_scale)**. I know next to nothing about those and if my procrastination-inclined mind hadn't insisted on, er, investing so much time in hanging around PSE, I would have never heard of them. `:)`

Why can't the blank be filled?

> The fifth scale is **[Mixolydian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixolydian_mode)**. It isn't named after a region; there were no Mixolydians. It just means "mixed Lydian".

Comment: One of my favourite things about PSE is exactly that which you mention here - the fact that out of nowhere you can suddenly end up down a rabbit hole studying semaphore or the life of Nikola Tesla or the inner workings of D&D and even though it is _completely_ irrelevant to your life, it is still somehow richer for it!

Comment: Oh, I wasn't complaining! I'm a rich man ... in a way.

Comment: Your richness came across in your comments :) I was merely remarking that I too know that feeling well!